# how to access endpoints from a remote machine

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ubuntu-18.04

I am running an ASP.NET Core 2.2 API on a Ubuntu 18.04x64 server that has a public IP address. It was developed on a Windows machine, and while running on IIS, all the endpoints work fine with the localhost. Once it is on the ubuntu server running using the dotnet command, I can't access the endpoints from my windows machine via the public IP address.

I tried adding this to my Program.cs file:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
     .Build();
```

As well as

```
"WebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": 
      "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000;http://*:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
```

to my launchSettings.json

When I go to the public IP address in my browser, I get the welcome to nginx webpage, but when I go to /api/ping I get a 404 error. What else am I missing?

Comment: "When I go to the public IP address in my browser, I get the welcome to nginx webpage" - That sounds like you're going to *just* the IP, i.e. `http://X.X.X.X` with no port. Based on what you have here, you'd need to go to `http://X.X.X.X:5000` instead. If you're trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy, it doesn't seem that that is set up properly.

Comment: Appending the port will time out the request @ChrisPratt